# Report Viewer Configuration Error on Shared Hosting

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, reportviewer, report-viewer2012

I have developed ASP.NET Application which requires ReportViewer for functionality. My Site is working perfectly well on localhost. I was asked by my shared hosting provider to upgrade the ReportViewer version from 11 to 12 which I did and it is working fine on local host. But on shared hosting space I am getting below error:
**ReportViewer Configuration Error**

> The Report Viewer Web Control HTTP Handler has not been registered in the application's web.config file. Add  to the system.web/httpHandlers section of the web.config file, or add  to the system.webServer/handlers section for Internet Information Services 7 or later.

**My Web.Config file**

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <customErrors mode="Off"/>
    <httpHandlers>
      <!--<add path="Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd" verb="*" type="Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.HttpHandler, Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=000000000000" validate="false"/>-->
      <add path="Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd" verb="*" type="Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.HttpHandler, Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=000000000000" validate="false"/>   

      </httpHandlers>
    <compilation targetFramework="4.5">
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=000000000000"/>
        <add assembly="Microsoft.ReportViewer.ProcessingObjectModel, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=000000000000"/>
        <add assembly="Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=000000000000"/>

      </assemblies>
      <buildProviders>
        <!--<add extension=".rdlc" type="Microsoft.Reporting.RdlBuildProvider, Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=000000000000"/>-->
      <add extension=".rdlc" type="Microsoft.Reporting.RdlBuildProvider, Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=000000000000"/>
      </buildProviders>
    </compilation>
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5"/>
    <!--<sessionState timeout="1" />-->
    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="login.aspx" timeout="40" slidingExpiration="true"/>
    </authentication>
    <!--<sessionState timeout="20"></sessionState>-->
  </system.web>
  <!--<authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="CompanyMaster.aspx" />
    </authentication>-->

  <system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
    <handlers>
      <!--<add name="ReportViewerWebControlHandler" preCondition="integratedMode" verb="*" path="Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd" type="Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.HttpHandler, Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=000000000000"/>-->
    <add name="ReportViewerWebControlHandler" preCondition="integratedMode" verb="*" path="Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd" type="Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.HttpHandler, Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=000000000000"/>
    </handlers>
    <!--<defaultDocument>
    <files>
      <clear />
      <add value="Login.aspx" />
    </files>
  </defaultDocument>-->
  </system.webServer>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="ValidationSettings:UnobtrusiveValidationMode" value="None"/>
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

**I have also added all the 3 DLL files in BIN Folder**

Can anyone please guide me where I am wrong?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Issue was resolved finally!

I changed the IIS Application Pool from Integrated to **Classic**. It's working perfectly well now!